# Sass compile compressed in CLI

Tags: sass

```
sass input.scss:output.css
```

works well on my server, but the output is uncompressed.

Can I pass arguments to compress the css like the following?

```
sass input.scss:output.css =compressed
or sass input.scss:output.css minified
```

?

```
watch
```

is not supported on my server and there is no option to get it to work.
Instead, I have to manually compile the sass via the CLI statement on line 1 of this post

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the standard Ruby-style flags. Try this:

```
sass input.scss:output.css --style compressed
```